# iOS SwiftUI: ActionSheet custom style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, actionsheet

I'm trying to change the text color and the background color of the ActionSheet in SwiftUI.

This is the code of my actionSheet:

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isCustomItemSelected) {
        ActionSheet(
            title: Text("Add Item"),
            message: Text("Which item would you like to add?"),
            buttons: [
                .default(Text("Todo")),
                .default(Text("Event")),
                .cancel(Text("Cancel"))
        ])
}
```

And whatever I try, like tint color, foreground color etc.. It does not change the color.
How is the correct way to change it?
I imagine that SwiftUi does not have any API to style it, but I'm sure that should be any workaround.

Answer (score -1):

## Partial Solution

Create a custom configurator for the ActionSheet:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ActionSheetConfigurator: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var configure: (UIAlertController) -> Void = { _ in }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActionSheetConfigurator>) -> UIViewController {
        UIViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(
        _ uiViewController: UIViewController,
        context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActionSheetConfigurator>) {
        if let actionSheet = uiViewController.presentedViewController as? UIAlertController,
        actionSheet.preferredStyle == .actionSheet {
            self.configure(actionSheet)
        }
    }
}

struct ActionSheetCustom: ViewModifier {

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(ActionSheetConfigurator { action in
                // change the text color
                action.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
            })
    }
}
```

Than in the view, after the **.actionSheet** modifier add the custom modifier like follow:

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isCustomItemSelected) {
        ActionSheet(
            title: Text("Add Item"),
            message: Text("Wich item would you like to add?"),
            buttons: [
                .default(Text("Todo")),
                .default(Text("Event")),
                .cancel(Text("Cancel"))
        ])
    }
    .modifier(ActionSheetCustom())
```

I did not figure it out how to change the background color or how to make major customisation. I'm sure we should work on the **action** object where I'm changing the color.

Comment: Its not working for me.